# How to unlink a Supercell ID from CoC?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I accidentally linked my base with my friends Supercell ID in Clash of Clans.

Can we remove our linked Supercell ID?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to unlink your Supercell ID just go to Settings -> Help and Support. Next, press the Lost Account button and then press Contact Us. Write a message to Supercell to unlink your account. After you send your message, within 24hrs your account will become locked. The next day you can log in to your account and you will see the Supercell ID is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

So when you log into your coc, at the bottom right part of the screen, there should be 4 buttons. Tap on the button with gears on it. It's right above the shop button. There's a section that says supercell id. If it says connected and you don't want it to be connected. Tap on "connected" and it should say logged in as (insert email here) there's a button to the right of that, that says log out. I should be logged out by then